# Java How to make variable global in actionListener

Tags: java

I have `ActionListener` for `JCombobox`.

```
dataCombo.addActionListener(e->{

                Item selected_item_from = (Item) dataCombo.getSelectedItem();
                Item selected_item_to = (Item) dataComboTo.getSelectedItem();

                System.out.println(selected_item_from.getId());

 });
```

How to make variable `selected_item_from` and `selected_item_to` availability of outside of the `ActionListener`?

I use Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining these variables as global (as class members e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

A better method, however, is to make a method on your model that takes a parameter.  Pass the id of the selected item through that.

The problem with a global variable is it's global.  It can be changed by anyone, and it's effectively coupled to every method in the code.  Using a parameter couples the parameter only to the method called, and also makes for much easier testing.  [C.f. Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

```
public class MyGuiGlue {

  private Model model;

  public MyGuiGlue( Model model ) { this.model = model; }

  // ...
  dataCombo.addActionListener(e->{
            Item selected_item_from = (Item) dataCombo.getSelectedItem();
            Item selected_item_to = (Item) dataComboTo.getSelectedItem();

            model.myMethod( selected_item_from, selected_item_to );

 });

...
}
```

Remember that Swing is not thread safe.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html